# Javascript function to return PHP get_file_contents

Tags: php, jquery

I am stumped here, have asked this a few different ways. What I need to do is return the contents of a text file in PHP on click of an a tag.  I thought it would be easy enough to just have the click and ID of the anchor tag in the JS and put the PHP method in the template like so. $textPath is var that points to the file in the settings. It goes to a help section and the text file authenticates the user. So the UL ends up being www.blahblah.com/help

```
  <li><a id="help" target="_blank"><? echo file_get_contents($textPath);?> </a></li>

  //Simple JS (part of another 'open' function for the menu)

   $('#help').attr("href", "/help")
```

But it's still not working at all. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: If you want to insert content from php dynamically based upon a click event then you will need to make an ajax call to the server to obtain the content from your php script and then insert it into the document if the ajax call succeeds. Your code here will set the href value of a to "/help"

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you want. Please post sample contents of a `$textPath` file. Is this a single page app where the PHP is run beforehand, or are you expecting JavaScript to run PHP code on the client? If the latter, it isn't possible and requires AJAX as stated above by miknik

Comment: @Steve It's a single page ya, and the contents would just be a randomly generated string of something like 'ewir334329'

Comment: Then as miknik said, there is no way to do this without AJAX. PHP code cannot run on the client, it is a server-side language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highlighting a part of your code here:

```
<a id="help" target="_blank"><? echo file_get_contents($textPath);?> </a>
```

See you are using the shorthand echo tag. The opening tag should be `<?=` insead of `<?`. And since this is a shorthand echo tag, you don't need to use the echo construct.

This shall work fine:

```
<a id="help" target="_blank"><?=file_get_contents($textPath);?> </a>
```

> [Quoting from the PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php/)
>
> *echo* also has a shortcut syntax, where you can immediately follow the opening tag with an equals sign. Prior to PHP 5.4.0, this short syntax only works with the short_open_tag configuration setting enabled.
>
> ```
> I have <?=$foo?> foo.
> ```

Coming to the question, you want to return the contents of the file. Your best bet will be achieving this via AJAX.

You can output as you wish. The best way will be to make a separate php file for handling all the ajax calls and return the output as plain text. To authenticate the user, just include the auth.php file(assuming that you are using one) in the ajax.php page.

**ajax.php**

```
<php
//Below code checks if a GET request is sent
if (isset($_GET['path'])) {
echo file_get_contents($textPath);
}
?>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#help').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // Prevents the default action
  // Send an AJAX request
  $.get("ajax.php?path", function(s) {
    //s is the responsetext. It contains the response from the server
    your code here
  });
});
```

Comment: While you are correct, this does not provide an answer to the question.

Comment: I was told apparently you could create a JS variable with the php echo code but I haven't gotten this to work either. I give up ha.

Comment: Updated my post with the soluton